# Make Ruby 1.9 regard all source files to be UTF-8 encoded. (Even if recompiling the interpreter is necessary)

Tags: encoding, compilation, ruby-1.9.2

I want to port a rails app from Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.2. Some of the files contain umlauts like ä/ö/ü both within strings and comments.
The files were saved as UTF-8 but without a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (byte order mark) at the beginning.

As you might know, [Ruby 1.9 refuses to parse these files](http://ruby.runpaint.org/encoding#source), giving an `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)`

I was googling and reading a lot but the only solution to this seems to be to

- insert a BOM or
- insert `# coding: utf-8`

at the beginning of *each* file.

My editor of choice (gEdit) doesn't seem to insert a BOM. I also read that having a BOM is bad practice because it may break some editors, it also breaks shell scripts if you want to use the shebang notation.

***EDIT***: The BOM breaks the Ruby 1.8.7 parser, giving a `syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end (SyntaxError)` for the file!

I tried forcing the external encoding with ruby -Eutf-8:utf-8 but this seems to be ignored when calling rake (I tried: /home/malte/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake test).

So my question is:

As RVM is building ruby 1.9 from source anyway, **is there a build option or a patch to change the default encoding from US-ASCII to UTF-8**?

I took a quick look at the source code but couldn't find the line where the default is set (I'm no C expert, tough).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found a workaround:
[set the `RUBYOPT` environment variable](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2188-i18n-fails-with-multibyte-strings-in-ruby-19-similar-to-2038#ticket-2188-60), for example by executing

`export RUBYOPT=-Ku`

in your shell.

This will set -Ku als default option when calling ruby. You can now call all other tools which invoke ruby without worrying about parameters. `rails server` or `rake` works and regards all files as UTF-8. No BOM or magic comments necessary!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the only way I could get my tests to run with UTF-8 chars in my factories.

Comment: Apparently, the -Ku option will be deprecated.  The default_internal and default_external encodings work for input and output.  However, they do NOT set the file encoding.  AFAIK, file encoding can be set only with a BOM or magic comment.

Comment: @jpgeek No need to worry about deprecation; starting with ruby 2.0 the default source file encoding is UTF-8, so you won't even need `-Ku`.

Comment: @Kelvin I'm getting some of those errors on 2.2.0(-preview1), and -Ku fixed it, but I feel bad using something that's (apparently ?) deprecated...

Comment: @Ven I'm not sure what to tell you, because I don't have 2.2 installed. If you don't have the problem on 2.1 (installed on the same system & same environment), it might be a 2.2 bug. I'd recommend using a production-ready version unless you're willing to do deep troubleshooting.

Comment: It's fine for now, I guess. I'll do indeed try and get some more insights later...